# jasmine - How to do equality comparison between function and object method assigned with .bind?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, tdd

**Edit: My original question did not include `.bind` in funcToTest. That appears to be what's failing the test.**

I am testing a method that assigns a function to an object's property.

I want to verify that the newly created property equals the function. Neither `toBe` nor `toEqual` are getting the test to pass.

What's best practice in this case?

```
class TestClass {
    constructor() {
    }

    initMyObj() {
        this.myObj = {
            func: this.myFunc.bind(this) //it works fine without .bind
        }
    }

    funcToTest() {
        console.log('Thanks for reading!');
    }
}


describe('TestClass', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.test = new TestClass();
    });
    it('should set "myObj.func" property to funcToTest method', function() {
        this.test.initMyObj();
        expect(this.test.myObj.func).toBe(this.test.funcToTest); //fails with `Expected Function to be Function.`
        expect(this.test.myObj.func).toEqual(this.test.funcToTest); //fails with `Expected Function to equal Function.`
    })
})
```

Also note - if I remove `.bind(this)`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by moving my `.bind` declaration to the constructor.

```
class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this)
    }

    initMyObj() {
        this.myObj = {
            func: this.myFunc
        }
    }

    funcToTest() {
        console.log('Thanks for reading!');
    }
}
```